# Reference a the state of HEAD before the last `pull` or `merge`

Tags: git, git-log, git-reflog

I find that I often do this.

- Run `git pull` or `git pull --rebase`
- Look at the standard output to see the changes

  ```
  From github.com:foo/bar
     3d8749e..b795f99  master  -> origin/master
  ```
- Copy ’n’ paste this version range to

  ```
  git log -p 3d8749e..b795f99
  ```

I wonder if there is is a way to specify “The state of `HEAD` before the last pull or merge“, so that I can simply always run the same command

```
git log -p HEAD@{before pull}..HEAD
```

Simply always using `HEAD@{1}` is close and might work for `git pull`, but not for `git pull --rebase`, because that adds multiple entries to the reflog:

```
$ git reflog
4111cc6 (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{0}: rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/master
4111cc6 (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{1}: pull --rebase: A local commit
b795f99 (origin/master, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{2}: pull --rebase: checkout b795f9924503c05da91b08e0e9ad3ffb48229bc8
d3379e5 HEAD@{3}: commit: A local commit
```

Comment: I think the diff between `HEAD@{before pull}..HEAD` is the same with `origin/master@{1}..origin/master@{0}`. Not sure if there's conflict.

Comment: @ElpieKay : That would be the difference between the last two fetches of `master`, not the difference between the local branch before and after the most recent fetch.  By which I mean, yes it often will be the same change, but definitely not in case of conflict and not necessarily exactly the same even with non-conflicting changes to the same file

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Yes, you are right. I also missed cases in which a different branch is pulled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One alternative is to use the branch reflog.  The `HEAD` reflog gets multiple entries during a rebase, but the branch reflog should just get one at the end.  (Works in my tests, at least.)  So it's not exactly "one command that's always the same", but

```
git diff master@{1}..master
```

is closer to what you want.

Another option is to use time-based reflog notation.  For example, if you know that `HEAD` hasn't moved in the past, say, 5 minutes, then immediately after the rebase you could say

```
git diff HEAD@{5.minutes.ago}..HEAD
```

and as long as there was no weird slow-down of 5 minutes after the first update to `HEAD`, this should be ok.  But of course if the `rebase` leads to conflict resolutions, there could be such a slow-down, and overall this is a half-baked solution that I mention only because it might *usuall* work with less variation between commands...

You could make note of the system time just before the merge, and say

```
git diff HEAD@{10:25:03}
```

to avoid depending on the rebase timing.  But now you're back to recording a value to plug into the command.

[*update* - deleted an option I originally mentioned, because it doesn't really do the right thing; working with a cold today, head's a little fuzzy.]

Comment: `master@{1}` is pretty close to what I was looking for, thanks!